# Is it possible to "emulate" virtual monitors like Windows does for remote desktop users?

Tags: display, remote-desktop

I want to remote desktop into macOS, but when I use a client like VNC Viewer on my Windows PC, it only allows me to go up to whatever resolution the macOS machine has (like 2560x1440 on an iMac).

My Windows setup has 3 monitors attached (4K, 2.5K, and 2K). If I use native Windows remote desktop into a tiny laptop with a 1920x1080 monitor, the program still opens up in fullscreen. It basically emulates having 3 monitors connected to the laptop.

I want the same but for macOS. What options do I have in that regard? Bonus points if it can run headless, so I can use it on a Mac Mini or a Mac Pro stashed away in a closet somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not using macOS Screen Sharing alone. It isn't really comparable to Windows Remote Desktop in terms of how it works.

Windows RD provides a service to the client, leaving it up to the client to handle the UI rendering.

macOS Screen Sharing / VNC relays screen contents to the client and returns user inputs to the server.

Comment: Is there a 3rd party application that can do it, then? I find it very hard to believe, this is so hard. It's native in Windows and macOS runs on like 20% of all computers, right?

Comment: That specific feature is native in windows because it was hard coded into windows. It doesn't follow that features of X are in Y just because X is 80% of the market share.